# Saving Images with Primefaces to DB2

Tags: image, jpa, primefaces, save

What is the best way to save an image loaded with PrimeFaces component fileUpload to DB2 using JPA?

fileUpload gives me a UploadedFile object...
in DB2 database I have a field with BLOB value and JPA representation of it in my project is:

```
@Lob()
private byte[] data;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this :

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
   byte[] data= event.getFile().getContents();
}
```

?